# Problem to connect to a wireless router in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless

I have a problem with connecting to a wireless router, when I chose **The Network** in the panel, is asks to enter the **Key**, I do, but after that he still try to access the network, but nothing happens, and it ask me again to enter the **Key**. Network is 100 % working with windows.

Comment: if you type network key right, but you can't connect that means there is problem with network security. Though it can be from your wireless router. Let me ask what network settings it uses ? (I don't mean password, eg. WPA2, encryption TKIP etc).

Comment: i use WEP Security

Comment: ah then set **Shared** instead of **Open** .. I used to have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you try to connect, enter right network key, and after that it asks for key again, that means something is with network settings. I am not sure what settings you use but to change them go to **System Settings** -> **Network** -> **Wireless** and choose that wireless network you want to connect. After that edit it, go to **Settings** -> Wireless **Security** and set there wireless security right options.

---

[image: editing wireless network]

---

So for your network it will be something like this:

---

[image: setting right settigns]